# How to link check boxes in 2 different cells of jqxGrid

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jqxgrid

I want 2 columns of checkboxes where the following is true.

If 'A' is toggled on then 'B' can be on/off
If 'A' is off then 'B' must also be off

Here's a fiddle with an example set of data, but I have no clue how I could go about adding this functionality. This is essentially just a front end validation of the data to prevent the user from accidentally creating 'impossible' scenarios. I'm not even sure where to start with customizing the checkboxes as described.

https://jsfiddle.net/6rc8uraf/11/

```
var data = [{
  name: "Person1",
  A: true,
  B: true
}, {
  name: "Person2",
  A: true,
  B: false
}, {
  name: "Person3",
  A: false,
  B: false
}];

var source = {
  localdata: data,
  datafields: [{
    name: "name",
    type: "string"
  }, {
    name: "A",
    type: "bool"
  }, {
    name: "B",
    type: "bool"
  }],
  datatype: "array"
};

var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
  width: "100%",
  source: adapter,
  editable: true,
  columnsresize: true,
  sortable: true,
  filterable: false,
  columns: [{
    text: "Name",
    datafield: "name",
    align: 'center',
    width: 150,
    menu: false
  }, {
    text: "A",
    datafield: "A",
    align: 'center',
    columntype: 'checkbox',
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
    menu: false
  }, {
    text: "B",
    datafield: "B",
    align: 'center',
    columntype: 'checkbox',
    menu: false,
    editable: true
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind `cellendedit` event to perform actions after [Programmatic Editing](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-cells-editing.htm)

```
$('#jqxgrid').on('cellendedit', function (event) {
    if (event.args.datafield == 'A' && event.args.value == false) {
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('setcellvalue', event.args.rowindex, 'B', false) //set value to false
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('setcolumnproperty', 'B', 'editable', false)//disable further editing
    } else if (event.args.datafield == 'A' && event.args.value == true) {
        // $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('setcellvalue', event.args.rowindex, 'B', true)
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('setcolumnproperty', 'B', 'editable', true) //enable editing
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks didn't know of that event. Much appreciated.